# Radgrid selection inside scrolling div resets scroll position

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I have a RadGrid inside a div set to overflow auto. If you scroll down and select a row the div's scroll position gets reset to the top. Tried using built-in scroll functionality but this didn't work (layout breaks and only background of template cells scroll without scrolling other elements). Tried JavaScript to reset scrollTop property of div on active row changed but this also didn't work.

Comment: Why would it scroll back to the top?  Is there an AJAX postback happening?

Comment: No there aren't. It's looks like that on changing selcted or active row in a grid, `scrollIntoView` function called on a master table.

Comment: what is the problem with inbuilt scrolling?

Comment: @ImranRizvi   As I mentioned, the layout in my app breaks, but most importantly, when you scroll the cells' child controls remain fixed while the cells themselves (the backgrounds/borders/etc) scroll normally

Comment: I had a rad grid that has a fixed header while scrolling and bound column, template column and hierarical grid inside . This works fine for me. Do you want to see it online so that you can check if it is your rquirement?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found my own solution to this one.  I created two hidden fields - one that maintains the scroll position (ScrollPosition), and another that maintains the ID of the scrolling container div (ScrollingContainerID).  My RadGrid is embedded in a User Control, so I have a server-side method to set the div the grid is contained in:

```
public void RetainContainerScroll(HtmlGenericControl container)
{
    if (container.IsNotNull())
       ScrollingContainerID.Value = container.ClientID;
}
```

On the RadGrid, I set two client events:

```
<ClientEvents OnRowSelecting="RetainScrollPosition" OnRowClick="RestoreScrollPosition" />
```

Then I defined the following client-side functions:

```
function RetainScrollPosition(sender, eventArgs) {
   var container = GetScrollingContainer();
   if (container == null)
      return;
   SetRetainedScrollPosition(container.scrollTop);
}

function RestoreScrollPosition(sender, eventArgs) {
   var container = GetScrollingContainer();
   if (container == null)
      return;
   container.scrollTop = GetRetainedScrollPosition();
}

function GetScrollingContainer() {
   var scrollingContainerField = document.getElementById("<%= ScrollingContainerID.ClientID %>");
   if (scrollingContainerField == null)
      return null;
   var containerID = scrollingContainerField.value;
   if (containerID == null || containerID.length == 0)
      return null;
   var container = document.getElementById(containerID);
   return container;
}

function GetRetainedScrollPosition() {
   var scrollPositionField = document.getElementById("<%= ScrollPosition.ClientID %>");
   if (scrollPositionField == null)
      return 0;
   return scrollPositionField.value;
}

function SetRetainedScrollPosition(scrollPosition) {
   var scrollPositionField = document.getElementById("<%= ScrollPosition.ClientID %>");
   if (scrollPositionField == null)
      return;
   scrollPositionField.value = scrollPosition;                        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to handle the scroll position loss when using `<DIV>` tags.

Add the following function, so that it is accessible to all your pages where you want to control scroll positions.

```
 protected void RetainScroll(string ids, bool isPostBack)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(ids))
            return;
        //register js method on page load event to set the previous scroll position.
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, Page.GetType(), "scroll", "javascript:RSSetScroll();", true);

        if (isPostBack)
        {
            //just register startup call and return
            return;
        }
        string[] allDivs = ids.Split(new char[] { ',' });
        if (allDivs.Length <= 0)
            return;
        //construct the js functions
        StringBuilder setScroll = new StringBuilder(512);
        StringBuilder onScroll = new StringBuilder(512);
        setScroll.Append("function RSSetScroll(){");
        onScroll.Append("function RSOnScroll(tdiv, hvar) {");
        foreach (string div in allDivs)
        {
            string hVar = div + "__h";
            Page.RegisterHiddenField(hVar, "0:0");

            setScroll.Append("if(document.getElementById('" + div + "')!=null) document.getElementById('" + div + "').scrollTop = 0;");
            setScroll.Append("if(document.getElementById('" + div + "')!=null) document.getElementById('" + div + "').scrollLeft = 0;");
            setScroll.Append("if(document.getElementById('" + div + "')!=null) document.getElementById('" + div + "').scrollTop = document.getElementById('" + hVar + "').value.split(':',2)[0];");
            setScroll.Append("if(document.getElementById('" + div + "')!=null) document.getElementById('" + div + "').scrollLeft = document.getElementById('" + hVar + "').value.split(':',2)[1];");

            Control ctrl = Page.FindControl(div);
            if (ctrl != null)
                if (ctrl.GetType() == typeof(HtmlGenericControl))
                {
                    ((HtmlGenericControl)(ctrl)).Attributes.Add("onscroll", "javascript:RSOnScroll(this,'" + hVar + "')");
                }

        }
        setScroll.Append("}");
        onScroll.Append("document.getElementById(hvar).value = tdiv.scrollTop +':'+tdiv.scrollLeft;");
        onScroll.Append("}");
        //insert js functions to page
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(Page), "RC", setScroll.ToString() + onScroll.ToString(), true);
    }
```

This function will inject a hidden variable, to which scroll positions will be saved on post backs, for different DIV tags. When the page renders, relevant scroll positions will be set back to DIV tags. I am using this technique to set scroll positions.

This is how you use this function in your code behind file :

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RetainScroll("divClientID1,divClientID2,divClientID3", IsPostBack);
}
```

Don't worry about the `IsPostBack` condition, it is handled inside the method itself.
The sample call above will save scroll positions for `divClientID1`, `divClientID2` and `divClientID3` during postbacks to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Won't setting flag called SaveScrollPosition to value "true" work for RadGrid?

Comment: I think he has used `DIV` tag for scrolling the grid.

Comment: @AYK is correct.  I tried SaveScrollPosition just for the heck of it, but it's contained in a div and it's the div that is scrolling.

Comment: @SeanRich Why don't you try implementing my answer provided below ? I am sure it will work for you. Just make sure that you call it with proper `DIV` tag ids. Mark as answer if it works for you. :)

Comment: @AYK   Apologies.  I had to move past this problem to other issues, and I haven't gotten back to it.  You're answer is thorough and reasonable so I've marked it as the answer.  I'll report back once I've tested it.

Comment: @SeanRich - Thanks for the update, but I am more curious about resolving this problem, because even I had faced many issues with this. That is why commented. Let me know how it goes for you and would be always ready to help you further.

Comment: @AYK Unfortunately, your solution didn't work.  I did come up with a workable solution of my own though.  See my answer below.